# How to extend SD card for OS

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I read multiple answers and tried the suggestions, but still cannot solve the issue.
So my Raspian OS is 15GB, but SD card is 32GB.

I used raspi-config to Extend the file system. However after extend when I do
df -h it says:

> > df -h
> > Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
> > /dev/root 15G 11G 3.2G 77%
> > /devtmpfs 404M 0 404M 0%
> > /dev tmpfs 437M 50M 387M 12%
> > /dev/shm tmpfs 437M 6.1M 431M 2%
> > /run tmpfs 5.0M 4.0K 5.0M 1%
> > /run/lock tmpfs 437M 0 437M 0%
> > /sys/fs/cgroup
> > /dev/mmcblk0p1 253M 40M 213M 16%
> > /boot tmpfs 88M 0 88M 0%
> > /run/user/1000

I see only 15Gb is used. But when I do

```
cat /proc/partitions 
1 0 4096 ram0   
...  
179 0 15558144 mmcblk0   
179 1 262144 mmcblk0p1   
179 2 15287808 mmcblk0p2
It shows that there are 2 15GB disks.
```

So how to make my OS to use all 32GB of my SD card space?

Comment: The listing DOES NOT show 2 disks. What does sudo fdisk -l show?

Comment: The simplest way to see what partitions your SD card has is to use `gparted` (you might need to install it first)

Comment: I installed gparted, it just shows one device: /dem/mmcblk0. Which is 15GB only.
But my SD card is 32GB. I can see it in Windows

Comment: fdisk -l just print /dev/mmcblk0 - 15G and thats all